# Potential memory leak on Springboot 3.x + Webflux on multipart upload

Tags: spring-boot, memory-leaks, spring-webflux, multipartform-data, spring-boot-3

Since I've upgraded my application from spring-boot 2.7 to 3.x (Im currently using 3.1.0), I'm experiencing a constantly memory usage increase of the memory used by the application when uploading files.

On a quest to find the root cause I've tried to remove all potential code that could be causing the leak until I get only a controller that receives the multipart file upload:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = ["/blob"])
class BlobController {
    // Upload blob
    @PutMapping(value = ["/test"], consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])
    fun uploadBlobAsync(@RequestPart("blob", required = true) blob: Mono<FilePart>, ): Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> {

        logger.info("Uploading @{}", LocalDateTime.now())

        return blob
            .flatMap { filePart ->
                filePart
                    .content()
                    .map { dataBuffer ->
                        try {
                            val bytes = ByteArray(dataBuffer.readableByteCount())
                            dataBuffer.read(bytes)
                            bytes
                        } finally {
                            DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer)
                        }
                    }
                    .collectList()
                    .map { _ ->
                        ResponseEntity.ok("OK")
                    }
            }
    }

    companion object {
        private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BlobController::class.java)
    }
}
```

I've done some loading tests, 500 requests with a 1MB file and what I observe is that the memory usage increases around ~7MB on each run, even though the heap memory remains stable, which lead to think it's off heap memory where the issue resides.

[Memory usage chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcCiT.png)

I'am running this application on a k8s environment.

You can find the sample app code I'm using to investigate this behaviour [here](https://github.com/brsimoes/webfluxmemoryleak/tree/main)

Can someone point me on the direction of where the problem may reside.

Thanks in advance.